# reverse on @list_route with custom url_path

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

If I have a viewset with the following code:

```
class ExtraRouteViewset(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    @list_route(methods=['get'])
    def somefunction(self, request):
        return Response({
            'key': 'value',
            'reverse': reverse('extraroute-somefunction'),
        })

    @list_route(methods=['get'], url_path='arguments/(?P<thing>[^/]+)')
    def arguments(self, request, thing):
        return Response({
            'key': thing,
            'reverse': reverse('extraroute-arguments', kwargs={'thing': 'something'}),
        })
```

I would expect both methods to work. However, the second `reverse` raises a `NoReverseMatch`. Examining the url patterns (by navigating to a non-existing url) shows the following url patterns:

```
^demo/ ^ ^extraroute/arguments/(?P<thing>[^/]+)/$ [name='extraroute-arguments/(?P<thing>[^/]+)']
^demo/ ^ ^extraroute/arguments/(?P<thing>[^/]+)/\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)$ [name='extraroute-arguments/(?P<thing>[^/]+)']
^demo/ ^ ^extraroute/somefunction/$ [name='extraroute-somefunction']
^demo/ ^ ^extraroute/somefunction/\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)$ [name='extraroute-somefunction']
```

The view name seems to be `extraroute-arguments/(?P<thing>[^/]+)` instead of `extraroute-arguments`? And indeed, if I use `reverse('extraroute-arguments/(?P<thing>[^/]+)', kwargs={'thing': 'something'})` it works. Am I missing something very obvious here, or is this a bug in `django-rest-framework`?

This is using Django 1.8a and django-rest-framework 3.0.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, in the second example, you send `url_path='arguments/(?P<thing>[^/]+)'`. Django REST framework [use it](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/5688d8b73648c67fbe5ea003916dae04a7c5bba0/rest_framework/routers.py#L168) to create both an `URL pattern` and a `URL Name`. But [the implementation](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/5688d8b73648c67fbe5ea003916dae04a7c5bba0/rest_framework/routers.py#L35) is too pure to strip the regex expression.

#### Solution with a custom router

```
#inside urls.py
router = SimpleRouter()
router.routes.append(
    Route(
        url=r'^{prefix}/arguments/(?P<thing>[^/]+)$',
        name='{basename}-arguments',
        mapping={
            'get': 'arguments',
        },
        initkwargs={}
    ),
)
router.register('extraroute', ExtraRouteViewset, base_name='extraroute')
urlpatterns = router.urls
```

and then in the views.py remove the `@list_route` decorators since its no more needed *(and will cause a route clash)*

```
#inside views.py
class ExtraRouteViewset(viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    #...

    def arguments(self, request, thing):
        return Response({
            'key': thing,
            'reverse': reverse('extraroute-arguments', kwargs={'thing': 'something'}),
        })
```

I have to mention that this actually adds a hardcoded `Route` pattern inside the default `SimpleRouter` *(which has patterns for list, create, retrieve, update, partial update, destroy)*. This means that **every** viewset which get registered via this router instance will be able to implement an `arguments` method and this method will be called when the regex match it.

Comment: So, it could be classified as a bug then? The `replace_methodname` doesn't really work on these url paths, it would be nice if there would be an argument to supply the view name. I'll see if I can come up with a patch.

Comment: Yep, that would be very helpfull :)

Comment: After reviewing the question again i have to agree with maryokhin on GitHub, [nested routing](http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#nested-routes) on [drf-extensions](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions) really seams to be the more proper way to go. For completeness and correctness of my answer i'll try to edit it and add a solution with nested/custom routing.

Comment: OK, an example solution added.

Comment: @Todor, i think the actual solution is to add an endpoint argument for DRF's list_route and detail_route. It's [here](http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#controller-endpoint-name) in DRF Extensions but the doc said the action decorator is going to be deprecated soon.