# django Rest Framework - ViewSet with custom list view and URL parameter

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following setup:

I want to list all holidays of a specific year. That's why I leave out the default list view and implement my own like this:

```
class HolidayViewSet(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin, GenericViewSet):
@list_route()
def year(self, request, year=get_today().year):
    public_holidays = self.get_queryset().filter(date__year=year)
    page = self.paginate_queryset(public_holidays)
    if page is not None:
        serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
        return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
    serializer = self.get_serializer(public_holidays, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

If I use the default /holiday/year/ I get a result for the current year.

But whe I try to pass a parameter, I'll get a 404. The 404 page (in debug mode) even shows me the correct URL pattern:

```
api/v1/ ^holiday/year/$ [name='holiday-year']
api/v1/ ^holiday/year\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='holiday-year']
```

In the [documentation](http://www.tomchristie.com/rest-framework-2-docs/api-guide/viewsets) this aspect is unfortunately not covered.

Any ideas why my route to `holiday/year/2017` is not working?

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841600/reverse-on-list-route-with-custom-url-path

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't seem like a clean solution.

Comment: You are using an really out of date version of the DRF documentation. What your version of Django REST framework ? This part explains how the urls are built: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter

Comment: Thanks for the input. But django tells me that there is already a route. I'd like to use it without the hazzle of creating separate routes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, my workaround is using `django-filter`.

**My filter:**

```
class HolidayFilter(filters.FilterSet):
    """
    This filter can be used to filter holidays by different values in API views or viewsets.
    See http://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.0/guide/rest_framework.html
    """
    year = filters.NumberFilter(name='date', lookup_expr='year')

    class Meta:
        model = Holiday
        fields = ['date']
```

**My viewset:**

```
class HolidayListViewSet(ModelViewSet):

    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # Apply filters
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())
        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        # Pagination
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)
        # Serializer
        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        # Response
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

**The URL:**

```
/api/v1/holiday/?year=2016
```

Answer (score 0):

DRF differentiates `list` and `detail` requests. `list` request is not expected to have additional path parameter(i.e. `/{id}`), while `detail` request, in opposite, defined by it.

What it means is `@list_route` decorator creates `/holiday/year` endpoint, and `@detail_route` will create `/holiday/{id}/year` endpoint.

Comment: Well, regarding to the 404 page, I get a route as I want. Even with list_route. But how can I use it?

Comment: @Ron "I get a route as I want" -- not quite. `^holiday/year\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$` generates path of format `holiday/year.[a-z0-9]+`. Not `holiday/year/{id}`

Comment: I know. But unfortunately - as I pointed out - I wasn't able to use this route. I didn't try id, I tried years.

Answer (score 0):

I think my approach is so simple but its useful. just determine your Router like below:

```
urlpatterns += [
    path(r'holiday/<int:year>/', TestListView.as_view()),
]
```

**The URL:**

api/v1/holiday/2016/

Then create your view like this:

```
class TestListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = TestSerializer

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        year = kwargs.get('year', '')
        query_set = Test.objects.filter(year__exact=year) # Test is my test model
        serializer = self.get_serializer(query_set, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```